# mysql, get tree comments with pagination (adjacency list)

Tags: php, mysql

I have read a lot of information about mysql tree adjacency list

I want to display the 10 most recent comments and ALL replies to this comment ( or where 10 comments `where parentId is null and level = 1` but take all comments where `exists parentId and level = 2` )

my table with data:

[mysql comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vb3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). Similar to the following code :

```
WHIT 
    CTE1 AS (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parentId is null and level = 1)
SELECT * FROM CTE1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE parentId IN (SELECT id FROM CTE1) AND level = 2
```